# How to get list for a property of a class from its collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have scenario where I need to get the collection of values of a property of class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCollection : List<Person>
{
    public object[] GetValues(string propertyName)
    {
        // best way to implement this method?
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to avoid the much iterations. Any idea will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be one that uses LINQ's `Select` method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCollection : List<Person>
{
    public object[] GetValues(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "Name")
        {
            return this.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        }
        else if (propertyName == "Property1")
        {
            return this.Select(p => p.Property1).ToArray();
        }
        else if (propertyName == "Property2")
        {
            return this.Select(p => p.Property1).ToArray();
        }

        // best way to implement this method?
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can also use expression trees to allow for a type-safe accessor lambda to be used as an argument:

```
public object[] GetValues(Expression<Func<Person, object>> propertyNameExpression)
{
    var compiledPropertyNameExpression = propertyNameExpression.Compile();

    if (propertyNameExpression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        return this.Select(compiledPropertyNameExpression).ToArray();
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid lambda specified. The lambda should select a property.");
}
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
var personNames = personCollection.GetValues(p => p.Name)
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit of Linq magic:

```
public object[] GetValues(Expression<Func<Person, object>> exp)
{
    var function = exp.Compile();
    return this.Select(function).ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
// assuming coll in a PersonCollection
var names = coll.GetValues(p => p.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple idea without using reflection would be like this:

```
public partial class PersonCollection: List<Person> {
    public object[] GetValues(String propertyName) {
        return (
            from it in this
            let x=
                "Name"==propertyName
                    ?it.Name
                    :"Property1"==propertyName
                        ?it.Property1
                        :"Property2"==propertyName
                            ?it.Property2
                            :default(object)
            where null!=x
            select x).ToArray();
    }
}
```

But I'd rather return an `IEnumerable` for not to enumerate eagerly:

```
public partial class PersonCollection: List<Person> {
    public IEnumerable GetValues(String propertyName) {
        return
            from it in this
            let x=
                "Name"==propertyName
                    ?it.Name
                    :"Property1"==propertyName
                        ?it.Property1
                        :"Property2"==propertyName
                            ?it.Property2
                            :default(object)
            where null!=x
            select x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Reflection

Person P = new Person();
object obj = p.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(p, null);

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
public object[] GetValues(string propertyName)
{
    List<object> result = new List<object>();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperty(propertyName);
    this.ForEach(person => result.Add(propertyInfo.GetValue(person)));
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working program

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCollection : List<Person>
{
    public object[] GetValues(string propertyName)
    {
        var result = new List<object>();
        foreach (Person item in this)
        {
            result.Add(item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(item));
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new PersonCollection();
        collection.Add(new Person(){Name = "George", Property1 = "aaa", Property2 = "bbbb"});
        collection.Add(new Person(){Name = "Peter", Property1 = "ccc", Property2 = "dddd"});
        var objects = collection.GetValues("Property1");
        foreach (object item in objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with entity framework,
you can use  `this.GetAll();`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using that.